# Code Coverage for browser unit tests

Tags: javascript, code-coverage

We are writing unit tests for library where test cases are on client side. And we need to see code coverage for this library. We have our own custom wrapper and we are not using nodejs on server side is on python. Is there a suitable tool for this job?

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible via Chrome dev-tools (As of Chrome 59). See [this post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a clientside javascript library `karma` is a pretty good choice. It is quite easy to learn and it gives you alot of functionality:

http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html

Karma got a `coverage` report which gives you information about code coverage. Combined with `Jasmine` you get a solid testing suite.